# get value Session

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, session

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
var summaryFieldDB = from b in dc.PropertyCompanies where (b.SummaryField.Contains(txtSearch)) select b;

Session["summaryField"] = summaryFieldDB;
```

now how can access to field summaryFiledDB???

if use this

```
  System.Data.Linq.Table<PropertyCompany> result = (System.Data.Linq.Table<PropertyCompany>)Session["summaryField"];
```

This line when run program say error:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[PropertyCompany]' to type 'System.Data.Linq.Table`1[PropertyCompany]

if i use Store Procedure Like `FullSearch`

```
Session["search"]   = dc.FullSearch("anv", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true);
System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<FullSearchResult> b = (System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<FullSearchResult>)Session["search"];
  foreach(var item in b)
  {
   //work with fields
  }
```

this work fine!!!

But I do not want to work with the Stored Procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I query isn't a table. IMO, you should settle on something like a `List<T>` here:

```
Session["summaryField"] = summaryFieldDB.ToList();
```

and

```
var result = (List<PropertyCompany>)Session["summaryField"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like...

```
List<PropertyCompany> result = (List<PropertyCompany>)Session["summaryField"];
```

Since you are store the collection of type `PropertyCompany`

Comment: this line say error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[PropertyCompany]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PropertyCompany]'.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Sql uses deferred Loading (lazy loading) meaning no data is executed until you finish off your expression with .ToList() etc, i.e. specify how you want your data

Change this to (Added ToList)

```
var summaryFieldDB = (from b in dc.PropertyCompanies where (b.SummaryField.Contains(txtSearch)) select b).ToList()
```

And (cast with List)

```
  List<PropertyCompany> result = (List<PropertyCompany>)Session["summaryField"];
```